# Generating iOS certificates and profiles

Tags: ios, codenameone

Want to build iOS App designed With codenameone and Netbeans IDE.
I need to create certificates and profiles but when clicking the "Generate" button in the iOS project properties form, I get the following alert message:

> "Please use Codename One Settings to access the certificate wizard"

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the message says and going to the settings page?

Comment: Hi Simon. Thanks for your answer. My concern is how to access the Codename One Settings with Netbeans IDE. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project. Select `Codename One` in the menu. Then select `Codename One  Settings` (or `Codename One Preferences`). The certificate wizard is there you can scroll by swiping to see the options in that UI, install extensions etc.